# Rotate a triangle around itself in c using three vertixes

Tags: c, rotation, allegro

I need to rotate a triangle (called ship) around itself.
Here is what I got so far, but it doesn't work. It keeps getting smaller and smaller until it disappears.

```
void RotatePoint(Point *P, float angle)
{
    float theta = angle * (180/3.1415);
    P->x = (P->x * cos(theta)) - (P->y * sin(theta));
    P->y = (P->y * cos(theta)) + (P->x * sin(theta));
}

void RotateShip(Ship *ship)
{
    Rotate(&ship->A, rotateAngle);
    Rotate(&ship->B, rotateAngle);
    Rotate(&ship->C, rotateAngle);
}
```

Point P is the Point I want to rotate, and Point C is the center of the triangle. I thought that if I rotate all three vertixes, the triangle will rotate.

In my case, I initialize this way:

```
void initShip(Ship *ship)
{
    ship->center.x = (SCREEN_W)/2.0;
    ship->center.y = (SCREEN_H)/2.0;
    ship->A.x = 0;
    ship->A.y = -5;
    ship->B.x = 15;
    ship->B.y = 25;
    ship->C.x = -15;
    ship->C.y = 25;
    ship->color = al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Ship A, B and C are the distance from the center of the triangle. I draw it adding the A, B and C to the center vertix.

```
A=-0.699857,-19.963261
A=-0.000857,-19.951065
A=-0.699001,-19.914387
A=-0.001712,-19.902250
A=-0.698147,-19.865631
A=-0.002565,-19.853554
```

Im pressing one key back and one key forth, making it rotate clockwise and anticlockwise. notice how A is shrinking.
I don't know what I do. I should be going back to 20.00 when it reaches the top. This way my triangle is shrinking.
I'm using cos(0.035) and sin(0.035), meaning 2 degrees.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What have you done to debug it?

Comment: It just vanishes. the drawing function is this:

`void drawShip(Ship *ship) {
 al_draw_triangle(ship->center.x + ship->A.x, ship->center.y + ship->A.y, ship->center.x + ship->B.x, ship->center.y + ship->B.y, ship->center.x + ship->C.x, ship->center.y + ship->C.y, ship->color, 1);
}`

When I press the key to rotate it, it vanishes. Something must be wrong with my math but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Please make a [mcve], no need for the whole drawing and other graphics stuff, just a main() which prints the coordinates sevaral times; demonstrating how they get smaller, especially how fast.

Comment: Among other things I want to see the types of the coordinates you are using. Int? Float? Double?

Comment: Do the coordinates get smaller, relative to the center? Or does the ship also move towards (0,0)?

Comment: Does the ship only shrink, or also rotate?

Comment: What is the difference between `Rotate(...)` as called, and `RotatePoint(...)` as defined? Whatis `rotateAngle` as used inside `RotateShip(...)`?

Comment: Your value for *pi* is inaccurate.  Use `M_PI` defined in `<math.h>`

Comment: The coordinates you show seem to confirm the slow-shrinking problem caused by storing coordinates instead of angle. Does the solution I proposed improve it?

Comment: Yes! The problem is solved. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The OP has a classic bug: using a temporary (or intermediate) value where the original/initial value should be used instead.

As a simplified example, consider a case where you have three variables, `a`, `b`, and `c`, and want to rotate their values one variable to the left:

```
    a = b;
    b = c;
    c = a;  /* Oops! Won't work! */
```

The last assignment is a problem, because `a` is no longer the original value!  You cannot order the assignments in a way that would avoid this problem; the only thing that changes is which variable will suffer from the problem. To fix the problem, you need to use a new temporary variable to hold the original value:

```
    t = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
    c = t;
```

---

In OP's case, the ship structure should not mix the current shape of the ship, and the true/unrotated shape of the ship, in the same variables. Even if you avoid the abovementioned problem, you'll still suffer from accumulated rounding errors; it might take hours of gameplay, but eventually your ship would end up looking different.

The solution is to describe the ship shape in separate variables, or using constants in the ship update function.)

Let's say we have a variable `dir` that specifies the direction in radians, rotated counterclockwise from up, 0 being up (towards negative y axis), π/2 (and -3π/2) left (towards negative x axis), π (and -π) down, 3π/2 (and -π/2) right, and so on. If `deg` is in degrees, `dir = deg * 3.14159265358979323846 / 180.0`. We can also use the `atan2()` function to find out `dir`: `dir = atan2(-x, y)`.

When `dir = 0`, OP wants `A = { 0, -5 }`, `B = { 15, 25 }`, and `C = { -15, 25 }`. If we define `Adir = 3.14159`, `Ar = 5`, `Bdir = -0.54042`, `Br = sqrt(15*15+25*25) = 29.15476`, `Cdir = 0.54042`, and `Cr = 29.15476`, then the ship vertices are

```
A.x = center.x + Ar*sin(dir + Adir);
A.y = center.y + Ar*cos(dir + Adir);
B.x = center.x + Br*sin(dir + Bdir);
B.y = center.y + Br*cos(dir + Bdir);
C.x = center.x + Cr*sin(dir + Cdir);
C.y = center.y + Cr*cos(dir + Cdir);
```

If the OP wants to fix the ship shape in the rotateShip function, then

```
void rotateShip(Ship *s, double rotateAngle)
{
    s->A.x = s->center.x +  5.00000 * sin(rotateAngle + 3.14159);
    s->A.y = s->center.y +  5.00000 * cos(rotateAngle + 3.14159);
    s->B.x = s->center.x + 29.15476 * sin(rotateAngle - 0.54042);
    s->B.y = s->center.y + 29.15476 * cos(rotateAngle - 0.54042);
    s->C.x = s->center.x + 29.15476 * sin(rotateAngle + 0.54042);
    s->C.y = s->center.y + 29.15476 * cos(rotateAngle + 0.54042);
}
```

---

Personally, I'd define the ship shape using a variable number of vertices:

```
typedef struct {
    double  x;
    double  y;
} vec2d;

typedef struct {
    vec2d        center;
    size_t       vertices;
    const vec2d *shape;     /* Un-rotated ship vertices */
    double       direction; /* Ship direction, in radians */
    vec2d       *vertex;    /* Rotated ship vertices */
} Ship;

const vec2d default_shape[] = {
    {   0.0, -5.0 },
    { -15.0, 25.0 },
    {  15.0, 25.0 },
};

void updateShip(Ship *ship)
{
    const double c = cos(ship->direction);
    const double s = sin(ship->direction);
    size_t       i;

    for (i = 0; i < ship->vertices; i++) {
        ship->vertex[i].x = ship->center.x + c*ship->shape[i].x - s*ship->shape[i].y;
        ship->vertex[i].y = ship->center.y + s*ship->shape[i].x + c*ship->shape[i].y;
    }
}

void initShip(Ship *ship, const size_t vertices, const vec2d *shape)
{
    ship->center.x = 0.5 * SCREEN_W;
    ship->center.y = 0.5 * SCREEN_H;

    if (vertices > 2 && shape != NULL) {
        ship->vertices = vertices;
        ship->shape    = shape;
    } else {
        ship->vertices = (sizeof default_shape) / (sizeof default_shape[0]);
        ship->shape    = default_shape;
    }

    ship->direction = 0;

    ship->vertex = malloc(ship->vertices * sizeof ship->vertex[0]);
    if (!ship->vertex) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    updateShip(ship);
}
```

In `updateShip`, we use 2D rotation by `ship->direction`, to rotate the ship model speficied by the vertices in `shape[]`, saving the rotated and translated coordinates to `vertex[]`.

```
    x_current = x_center + x_original * cos(direction) - y_original * sin(direction);
    y_current = y_center + x_original * sin(direction) + y_original * cos(direction);
```

as defined in e.g. the Wikipedia article on [rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)#Two_dimensions). Note that the original coordinates, `x_original` and `y_original` (or the values in the `shape[]` array in the Ship structure) are never modified.

This way you can let the player "upgrade" their ship by just changing the `shape` to point to a new ship shape, and `vertices` to reflect that number.

Comment: Do you want `default_shape` --> `default_ship`?

Comment: @chux: Good point, thanks! Actually, because I want to ensure OP (and others reading this answer) understand the difference between the current vertices of the ship (in its current translation and orientation), and the (original, unrotated and untranslated) shape of the ship, I decided to use `default_shape`. I don't know if it works (helps to distinguish between original/unrotated and current/rotated-and-translated), but it's the best I can do for now.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce fast shrinking (while also rotating) with coordinates in int.
(It would have been so much easier based on an MCVE....).
With coordinates in float, it shrinks much slower, but it still shrinks.

I relate that to the fact that your implementation collects all math errors (which computers always make) in a very visible way.

In order **to avoid shrinking altogether:**
Do not manipulate the relative coordinates in order to rotate. Instead store relative coordinates as constants, together with the ships orientation as an angle in double.

Then rotate by increasing/reducing the angle (wrapping around, to stay within -Pi ... +Pi).
Then draw by always applying the changing angle to the constant relative coordinates.

(I can only show you in detail, if you provide a MCVE.)

This way, the collected errors will only result in a slight and slowly growing misorientation,
which  most likely will not be noticed by the pilot - and then be corrected by the pilot.
"Hmm, the ship has not yet completed the 360 I wanted. Oh well, I will turn a little more."

On a side note, I do not trust the way you use angles as parameters to cos() and sin().
Or to put it differently, I think
`theta = angle * (180/3.1415);` -> `theta = angle;` for a U-turn via Pi.
`theta = angle * (180/3.1415);` -> `theta = angle * (3.1415/180);` for a U-turn via 180.
For your implementation you get a U-turn for the angle (Pi*3.1415/180), which I cannot see a reason for.

I also recommend to use appropriate constants from math.h (e.g. `M_PI`), instead of your own constant with 4 decimal places.